# RestKit response not mapped correctly

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have a mapped (not managed) object in restkit:

```
@interface SynchObj : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *event_data_c;
  @property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *fields;
@end
....
 mappingDict = @{@"event_data_c" :@"event_data_c",
                 @"fields"       :@"fields",
                 };
 responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SynchObj class]];
 [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingDict];
```

Now, when I receive the response :

```
response.body={"response":{"event_data_c":"2013-12-31 12:12:43":161,"server_id":77,"fields":{"nome":"pippo","cognome":"pippo"},"queue":""}}
```

In the success block of RestKit operation request I do:

```
SynchObj *item     = mappingResult.firstObject;
NSDictionary *JSON =
                    [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: item.fields
                                                                   options: kNilOptions
                                                                     error: &e] objectForKey:@"response"];
                    NSLog(@"WS: mapped response %@",JSON );
```

but the JSON dictionary is always null. I can see however that item.fields is not null.
What I am missing?

Comment: Not the help you're looking for perhaps, but have a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking): very easy to use and does all the JSON <-> object conversions, and is well maintained & documented.

Comment: @meaning-matters, RestKit uses AFNetworking, but where AFNetworking does JSON->`NSDictionary`, RestKit does JSON->Custom object with arbitrary mapping.

Comment: @Wain Thanks, that was silly of me. I was wrongly thinking about the obsolete JSONKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property to:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *fields;
```

(assuming that it is always a dictionary).

Then RestKit will unpack the JSON for you and store it directly so you don't need to do any subsequent manipulation in the `success` block.